# pseudovectors and covectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

The cross product of two vectors, $\vec{c}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$, is sometimes characterized as a pseudovector or axial vector.

On the other hand, if we look at the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as components of 1-forms, then the elemens of the cross product can be seen as components of a 2-form, and $\vec{c}$ should be seen as the Hodge dual of this 2-form. This, to me, is the real nature of pseudovectors.

My question is whether $\vec{c}$ can be seen as a covector, or a covariant 1-tensor. That is, if I write $a^i$ for the contravariat components of $\vec{a}$ and similar for $\vec{b}$, is there a tensor with components $T_{i,j,k}$ such that the covariant components of $\vec{c}$ are given by $c_k= T_{i,j,k}a^ib^j$?

Comment: You might want to look at the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$.

Comment: I have. But that is not a tensor, so that doesn't clarify things for me.

Comment: The epsilons are indeed the components of a tensor, called (no surprise) the Levi-Civita tensor. For relations to the ideas you were discussing, my Google-fu locates these: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucappgu/seminars/levi-civita.pdf, http://phys.columbia.edu/~cyr/notes/Electrodynamics/CPope-DiffForms-p56-67.pdf, the second of which seems very germane. But there are many others, available by searching for "levi civita hodge tensor", for example.

Comment: The second link you provide is very good, showing that the Levi-Civita symbol becomes a tensor when multiplied by the square root of the modulus of the determinant of the metric tensor.

Comment: I've converted that link, and your description, into a C-W answer, so that you can accept it and close out this question.

Comment: It's kinda bad form to change a question substantially after you've asked it -- it makes the answers that people have taken the trouble to provide look as if they're answering the wrong thing. Instead, you can ask a new question, with a pointer back to the one that inspired it.

Comment: I didn't think I was changing it "substantially", and I didnt't expect you to change your comment into an answer. And you can see from the time stamps that I did it before you did it. But ok, I will revert it.

Comment: Fair enough -- I didn't note the timestamps. But thanks for rolling back and therefore (I hope) closing out the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](http://phys.columbia.edu/~cyr/notes/Electrodynamics/CPope-DiffForms-p56-67.pdf) is relevant; it shows that the Levi-Civita symbol becomes a tensor when multiplied by the square root of the modulus of the determinant of the metric tensor.

Comment: Of course, this cannot be done unless you _have_ a metric, or at least a volume form.

Answer (score 4):

In general, covectors and pseudo-vectors are completely different concepts. Both come from some notion of duality.

If $V$ is a real vector space, the the dual space is the space of real linear functionals on $V$. Such things are called covectors. This notion of duality does not depend on the dimension of $V$.

There is another kind of duality which is Hodge duality. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, this associates totally antisymmetric tensors of rank $k$ with totally antisymmetric tensors of rank $n-k$. In $n=3$ this associates an antisymmetric tensor of rank $2$ with a "vector". These are the pseudo-vectors.

This explains why the "vector product" only exists in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: In particular, I think it's good to emphasize that the Hodge dual of a contravariant antisymmetric tensor will also be a *contravariant* antisymmetric tensor. That is, it's more natural to think of the bivector $a \wedge b$, transformed into the cross product by means of Hodge duality.